# Do I need to start AppCenter in every Activity's OnCreate or just the first one?

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

According to AppCenter's instructions when adding crash reporting and analytics to a Xamarin Android app:

> Inside your app’s MainActivity.cs, add the following using statements.

```
 using Microsoft.AppCenter;
 using Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics;
 using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;
```

> In the same file, add the following in the OnCreate() method.

```
 AppCenter.Start("xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
                    typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
```

However, I have a splash activity that runs before MainActivity that is prone to crashing - and the crashes won't get reported if the splash activity crashes before MainActivity gets the change to start and call `AppCenter.Start`.

So I also added `AppCenter.Start` to the start of SplashActivity. Does this mean I should remove `AppCenter.Start` from MainActivity in case I am starting multiple instances? Or are AppCenter instances separate to each activity and I need to add `AppCenter.Start` to every activity in the project (e.g. including my settings page activity)?

Comment: You need to opt in to the module(s) that you want to use, meaning by default no modules are started and you will have to explicitly call each of them when starting the SDK. Insert the following line inside your app's main activity class' onCreate-callback to use App Center Analytics and App Center Crashes: AppCenter.start(getApplication(), "{Your App Secret}", Analytics.class, Crashes.class);

Comment: Why don't you create an Application class and just do this there so it registers everything?

Comment: @G.hakim this sounds like a great idea. I've never used an Application class before - will try it

Comment: @G.hakim Could you please explain how to do this?

Comment: I have added the code you can check it

Answer (score 2):

Add a new class and inherit it from the Application class something like below:

```
 #if DEBUG
  [Application(Debuggable=true)]
  #else
  [Application(Debuggable = false)]
  #endif
 public class MainApp : Application
 {
    public MainApp(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
     {
        base.OnCreate();
     }
 }
```

Override the `OnCreate` method, now this method will be executed every time an activities `OnCreate` method is executed.

So you can simply add the crash analytics code here something like:

```
  public override void OnCreate()
 {
  base.OnCreate();
 AppCenter.Start("xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
                typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
  }
```

Comment: BUT If our app is not running and another app calls to our content provider of our app the `onCreate` of our Application class will NOT be called it is the only exception